# Passing argument between single quotes with classes

Tags: class, argument-passing

I never heard of this solution, but seems to be possible, i don't get why and how something like this is done.

Here it is an example:

> ```
> class SandboxPawn extends UDKPawn;
>
> DefaultProperties
> {
>     InventoryManagerClass=class'Sandbox.SandboxInventoryManager'
> }
> ```
>
> from: http://www.moug-portfolio.info/udk-weapon-basics/

Supposing that this kind of syntax is good and useful, why adopting this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the UnrealScript syntax for class literals.

http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Class_limiter#Class

Comment: So nothing special about it? I mean there is a reason for adopting this kind of solution?

Comment: I'm sure the designer of the language had a reason for it, probably to avoid ambiguity with other ways the keyword `class` is used. Perhaps if you look at the rest of the language's syntax it will be clear.